# Xpages Mobile Controls Not Working With Android Web View

Tags: android, android-webview, xpages

I have built an Xpages application that is currently surfaced in an iOS App and works fine. In my Android version, the same buttons do not work. I click it and nothing happens.

It works fine in Chrome on a PC.

It also works fine in the browser on my test Android device.

It just doesn't work in the web view embedded in the Android App.

Do I need to use a different type of webView?

Here is the java code:

```
package com.scoular;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import static com.XXXXX.utils.XXXXX.getPreference;

public class ExpensesActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expenses);
        String email = getPreference(this, R.string.email);
        String password = getPreference(this, R.string.password);
        String s = "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<form action=\"https://XXXXm/XXXXX.nsf?Login\"" +
                "method =\"POST\" name =\"LogonForm\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Username\"" +
                "value=\"" + email + "\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Password\"" +
                "value=\"" + password + "\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"RedirectTo\"" +
                "value=\"https://XXXXXX/XXXXX.nsf/m_XXXXXX.xsp\">" +
                "</form>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<script>" +
                "document.forms[0].submit()" +
                "</script>" +
                "</html>";
        File outputDir = this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
        File outputFile = null;
        try {
            outputFile = File.createTempFile("temp", "html", outputDir);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile);
            BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bWriter.write(s);
            bWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Got IOException: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.expenses_web_view);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

And here is the button part of the Xpage

```
            <xp:button value="Approves" id="button3"
                styleClass="mblButton" style="font-weight:bold">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler3">
                    <xp:this.action>
                                            <xp:actionGroup>
                            <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit"
                                var="document1"/>
                            <xp:confirm message="Approved" />
                            <xp:modifyField name="Action"
                                value="Approve" var="document1" />
                            <xp:saveDocument var="document1" />
                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var agent=database.getAgent("MobileApproval");
 var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument();
agent.runOnServer(doc.getNoteID()); }]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                            <xe:moveTo targetPage="homePage" />
                        </xp:actionGroup>
                    </xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It took a little while but I found the solution.

The method I was using was

setWebViewClient

which works for basic stuff and does run JavaScript, but will not acknowledge clicks on buttons.

I switched to

setWebChromeClient

and now everything works.